# Removing An App From Project - Will That Break The Related Android App?

Tags: android, firebase

We need to remove an app from our Firebase project, which seems easy, but I am curious if anything will happen in the Android app that's associated with the Firebase app?

Basically, if the Android app is making Firebase pushes, and no corresponding Firebase ID exists anymore, will the Android app have any issues, or will Firebase gracefully handle it?

Comment: "We need to remove an app from our Firebase project" Why? This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it's much more likely we can help if we know the reason you want to remove an app definition from Firebase yet somehow what the app in question to continue be able to work with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It will not effect to the other apps. For example, if you have 2 apps A & B. You remove A, then B still work. But, the app A will not be supported by the  current `Firebase` project anymore.

If you create another new `Firebase` project for A. Then, the below flow you should do.

1. Update new `google-services.json` file for A.
2. Make a force update version to make sure that the old version of A will be ended.
3. Publish new version of A.